# gwt-html5-database Alternative?

Tags: html, gwt

Resurrected an old project today and I see that gwt-html5-database has been taken off Maven. I see there is still an active project on GitHub (https://github.com/WSDOT/gwt-html5-database). Any recommended alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JSNI and worked directly with WebSQL. IndexedDB is still too buggy.